# Ajax refresh on jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to make a jquery checking if `#MyModal` exist, and if it dosent it should run the code `.hide` if it does, it should not make any changes. I have tried doing this, but it dosent work. Any idea why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "server", success: function (data) {
                    if ($("#myModal" + name).length == 0) {
                        $('body').hide();
                    };
                    salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
                }, dataType: "json"
            });
        }, 1);
    });
```

Comment: 1 millisecond is an extremely short amount of time for an interval.  For a given second, you are going to be making ~1000 ajax requests.

Comment: Also this interval is never ending.

Comment: Also where is `name` and `salesGauge` defined?

Comment: @Taplar I have not been able to make the if sentence work, without the + name, why i don't know. But it works when it is not in the ajax code. I just set it to 1 to test if it worked, and it didn't.

Comment: The thing i am trying to do now, is just to check if the id has been changes for instance, in inspect element, and if it has, it should hide body.

Comment: I would strongly suggest you up that interval to something like 1000, even for testing.  I wouldn't be surprised if you were creating so many ajax requests that the browser may cancel previously started requests once it starts hitting some threshold.  However, that is conjecture on my part.

Comment: I found a solution that works, i am not sure if it is the best´, but it works for now.

Comment: Are you really making an ajax call to the url `"server"`, or is that just shorthand in the question and in real life you're using a real URL?   Also, does the presence or absence of `#myModal` have anything to do with the ajax call?  (You don't appear to be making any use of the ajax data except to modify `salesGauge`, which doesn't seem to be related to the rest of the question, but again I'm not sure if that's real or just an artifact of the simplified code example)

Answer (score -1):

you should use this check for element exist, the condition you are trying is possibly wrong update your condition as;

```
if( !($('#myModal').length)){
//here do whatever
}
```

by using this condition it will help to solve problem according to your question.

Answer (score -1):

I got a fix for it myself, if it is the best, i don't know but this works

```
function CheckModal() {
            if ($("#myModal" + name).length == 0) {
                $('body').hide();
            };
        }
        setInterval(function () {
            CheckModal()
        }, 1000);
```

Is it better to be done like this, or should it be done in ajax?

Comment: Why do you think you need to use ajax?

Comment: But why?  Ajax is used to perform a network request without causing the page to reload.  If you do not need a network resource, or need to perform a network operation, using ajax does not make sense.